# EmEditor Auto-deploy all settings

Tags: registry, emeditor

I have created a Windows 10 Export (to reg file) of my optimal EmEditor set-up for my team.

Is there a silent way from command line (equivalent of Tools - Import and Export - Import all settings from a registry file) to deploy to all users in a batch file/script using EmEditor and command line switches?

Currently using v20.1 and users do not have admin rights on their machines. Would like to be able to deploy this silently moving forwards (via logon script if possible).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a batch file that you can run in Command Prompt.
If you save this file as `EEImportReg.bat`, and if the EmEditor settings have been exported to `C:\ExportedFolder` (where `exported.reg` file exists), you will run this as:

`EEImportReg.bat "C:\ExportedFolder"`

I would recommend running this batch file before you run EmEditor.

```
@echo off
if not exist "%1\exported.reg" (
    echo "%1\exported.reg" does not exist.
    exit /b
)
reg.exe import "%1\exported.reg"
xcopy "%1\AppData" "%appdata%\Emurasoft\EmEditor" /s /y /q
```